# How do I reach first and second plots from bode()

Tags: matlab

I know how to create the Bode plots with bode() function. If I want to overlap two or more systems frequency responses, I use

```
bode(sys1,sys2,...)
```

or

```
hold on
```

When I want to reach the plot in order to put a legend with text(), for instance, is easy to reach the second plot. Something like the figure pointer always returns to the second plot (phase graph).

i.e., if try these lines:

```
G = tf([1],[1 6]); figure(1); bode(G); text(10,-20,'text');
G = tf([1],[1 6]); figure(2); bode(G); text(10,-20,'text');
```

when I return to the first figure, with figure(1), and try

```
figure(1); text(10,-20,'text')
```

legend is displayed in the second plot (Phase plot)

I try these other lines:

```
P = bodeoptions; % Set phase visiblity to off
P.PhaseVisible = 'off';
G = tf([1],[1 6]);
figure(1); bode(G,P); text(10,-20,'text');
figure(1); text(10,-20,'text');
```

As you can see, even I turn off the phase plot visiblity, the legend is not displayed.

Essentialy, my question is, how do I reach first and second plots, one by one? I tried with subplot(), but it is pretty clear this is not the way Matlab traces these plots.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have two different figures, you can chance the pointer of figure as `figure(figure number)` typing in command window

Comment: It seems bode() and bodeplot() trace de Bode's graphs as a unit. If I use the number plot, Matlab points always this graph unit, to the second (the last object) plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all comes to getting into upper plot, since after `bodeplot` command the lower one is active. Intuitively one would want to call `subplot(2,1,1)`, but this just creates new blank plot on top of if. Therefore we should do something like this:

```
% First, define arbitrary transfer function G(s), domain ww 
% and function we want to plot on magnitude plot.
s = tf('s');
G = 50 / ( s*(1.6*s+1)*(0.23*s+1) );
ww = logspace(0,3,5000);
y = 10.^(-2*log10(ww)+log10(150));
hand = figure;                   % create a handle to new figure
h = bodeplot(G,ww);
hold on;
children = get(hand, 'Children') % use this handle to obtain list of figure's children

% We see that children has 3 objects:
% 1) Context Menu 2) Axis object to Phase Plot 3) Axis object to Magnitude Plot

magChild = children(3);          % Pick a handle to axes of magnitude in bode diagram.
% magChild = childern(2)         % This way you can add data to Phase Plot.
axes(magChild)                   % Make those axes current
loglog(ww,y,'r');
legend('transfer function','added curve')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get magnitude and phase data separately for each system using:

```
[mag,phase] = bode(sys,w)
```

now you can use `subplot` or `plot` to plot the diagram you want.

Comment: With figure(), Matlab points the second plot (phase).

i.e.

G=tf([1],[1 6]);figure(1);bode(G);text(10,-20,'text')
G=tf([1],[1 6]);figure(2);bode(G);text(10,-20,'text')

How do I reach the Mag plot in order to locate in (10,-20) the legend 'text'?

Comment: I edited original answer you can use ordinary plots using `mag` and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I was able to perform is taking into account axis position. It is not very clean but it works.
Here is the code to select mag plot:

```
ejes=findobj(get(gcf,'children'),'Type','axes','visible','on');
posicion=get(ejes,'pos');
tam=length(posicion);
for ii=1:tam
a=posicion{ii}(2);
vectorPos(ii)=a;
end
[valorMax,ind]=max(vectorPos); % min for choosing the phase plot
axes(ejes(ind))
```