# Change the fontsize of the axis of a bode plot in octave?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

This is the octave script

```
clear all;
close all;

pkg load control;

Ri1 = Ri2 = 10e6;
Cin = 2e-6;

R1 = 9e3;
R2 = 1e3;
Rl = 100;
C = 2e-6;

tau1 = ((Ri1*Ri2)/(Ri1 + Ri2)) * Cin;

H = tf([tau1 0],[tau1 1]);

Gain = R2/(R1+R2);

G = tf([C*Rl 0],[(C*R1 + C*(R1*R2)/(R1+R2)) 1]);

G = Gain * G;

bode(G*H);
set(gca,'FontSize',20,'Fontname','arial');
xlabel('Frequency','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold');
```

And is generating this graph:

[bode plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4hd8.png)

Does anyone know why just the second graph change the font size and how to make the change in both graphs?

Comment: If it is possible it could be plotted separately

Answer (score 1):

Simply relabelling y axis and title will help you change the font as you intended in final graph.

```
bode(G*H);
%set(gca,'FontSize',20,'Fontname','arial');
xlabel('Frequency','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold');
ylabel('Phase','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold');
title('Bode Diagram','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold')
```

but controlling each both plot's data label using set(gca,~) is somewhat tricky. You can refer to answer here for detailed information  ([How do I reach first and second plots from bode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925824/how-do-i-reach-first-and-second-plots-from-bode/44033867)).

I think it is much more easier to extract phase & magnitude graph separately and subplot them to control independently.

```
[magn,phas,w]=bode(G*H);

figure()
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(w, magn(:))
set(gca,'FontSize',20,'Fontname','arial');
title('Magnitude')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(w,phas(:))
set(gca,'FontSize',20,'Fontname','arial');
title('Phase')
```